# Executing AOP when some method is called from specific class

Tags: java, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I am new to AOP. I can successfully execute the AOP when some method of some class is executed.But i want to execute the AOP when some method of some class is called from other class. Is this type of implementation is possible in SpringAOP or AspectJ?

For Example,I have Class "A" having method getA.
I have successfully implemented, "when getA is executed, do something".
But i want " When getA is called from class "B", do something". 
Is it possible in Spring AOP or AspectJ?

Answer (score 1):

> When getA is called from class "B", do something". Is it possible in Spring AOP or AspectJ?

Yes, provided the object of `Class A` in `Class B` is injected. This is because, AOP is implemented by spring using proxies and hence the injected instances will be proxies wrapping the object of the class on which aspects are defined. So, as long as you call `getA()` method on spring-managed beans, the join points get executed.

Comment: If you can't do it in Spring's AOP, you can always drop back and just use a full AspectJ aspect.  Which gets you additional pointcuts and join points to play around with.